# How can I proove 0 <= a < b -> rem a b = a in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove this lemma

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Lia.

Open Scope Z_scope.
Import Z.

Ltac Zify.zify_post_hook ::= Z.to_euclidean_division_equations.

Lemma rem_pos : forall {a b : Z},
  0 <= a < b ->
  rem a b = a.
 intros. lia.
```

At this point I receive `Tactic failure:  Cannot find witness.` from `lia`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `lia` is for linear arithmetic, so I guess you want `nia`. But it still doesn't work. It's a pity. There is `rem_small` in the library to solve this, but I'm guessing this is not the single goal you care about.

Comment: Yes, this is a simplification. I need to check various proofs involving `rem`, regarding cyclic arithmetic found in programming languages when an overflow happens, anyway `rem_small` is helpful, thank you Ana!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search is your friend:

```
Require Import ZArith.

Open Scope Z_scope.
Import Z.

Lemma rem_pos : forall {a b : Z},
  0 <= a < b ->
  rem a b = a.
Proof.
  intros a b H.
  Search (rem ?a ?b = ?a).
  apply rem_small.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Afaik there is no dedicated proof automation for modulo arithmetic. Coq-hammer is able to solve it with e-prover and Z3 backends (coming soon in Coq Platform):

```
Require Import ZArith.
From Hammer Require Import Hammer.

Open Scope Z_scope.
Import Z.

Lemma rem_pos : forall {a b : Z},
  0 <= a < b ->
  rem a b = a.
Proof.
  hammer.
Qed.
```

But this is trivial for an ATP, so not a reasonable test. The problem is that one can't easily combine ATPs with the power of lia.

In my experience your best bet is `Search` an adequate lemma and solve the preconditions with lia.

Comment: Yeah, in my case I'm writing tactics for unfolding and massaging everything in way that lia can understand. I will take a look in `hammer` thank you!

Comment: I plan to do a Coq Platform release including coq-hammer next week. You might want to wait for that. Size hammer uses external ATPs and requires e.g. a non standard Z3 front end it is a bit tricky to install otherwise.